# What's the rank of $\sum_{i=1}^{m}x_{i}y_{i}^{T} \leq m$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

I have two sets of vectors: $\{x_{1}, x_{2}, ... , x_{n}\}$ and $\{y_{1}, y_{2}, ... , y_{n}\}$, I have to show that : rank  $[\sum_{i=1}^{m}x_{i}y_{i}^{T}]\leq m$.
They say to first show that rank of the $x_{i}y_{i}^{T}$ square matrix is equal to 1.

I did it saying that :

First we see that the $x_{i}y_{i}^{t}$ matrix has $rank = 1 $. Indeed, 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
A = x_{i}y_{i}^{t} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
x_{1}y_{1} && x_{1}y_{2} && \cdots && x_{1}y_{n}\\
x_{2}y_{1} && x_{2}y_{2} && \cdots && x_{2}y_{n}\\
\vdots && \vdots && \ddots && \vdots\\
x_{n}y_{1} && x_{n}y_{2} && \cdots && x_{n}y_{n}\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
can easily be reduced as : 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_{1}y_{1} && x_{1}y_{2} && \cdots && x_{1}y_{n}\\
0 && 0 && \cdots && 0\\
\vdots && \vdots && \ddots && \vdots\\
0 && 0 && \cdots && 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
because each row is a linear combination of the first one. Thus $rank = 1$.

But I don't understand what the rank of a sum means... And I tried with a simple example and It didn't worked. [EDIT: this is wrong] **I see that this sum is like the trace of the matrix,** but I don't see the purpose to calculate the rank of a trace and even if there is a purpose I don't know how should I do it.
Thanks for your help ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: First we have the fact that the rank of the matrix $x_{i}y_{i}^{T}$ is 1.

Then we use the rank inequality $r(A+B) \leq r(A)+r(B)$

Comment: ahhh ok, the sum doesn't mean the trace of the matrix. Is the sum of ranks of matrices right?

Comment: @Moleson Yes, the sum means the sum of rank.

Answer (score 2):

The rank of a matrix $A$ equals the dimension of the space generated by the images $Az$. If $A$ has the form $A = \sum_{i = 1}^{m}x_{i}y_{i}^{t}$, then $Az = \sum_{i = 1}^{m}(y_{i}^{t}z)x_{i}$ is a linear combination of the $m$ vectors $x_{1}, \dots, x_{m}$. Hence the space generated by the images $Az$ is contained in the span of the vectors $x_{1}, \dots, x_{m}$, so has dimension at most $m$.